# Mass change datatype and rename of dependent store procedure variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, metadata, rename, refactoring-databases

I am in the process of optimising my database and I was thinking of changing the datatype for some columns from DATETIME to SMALLDATETIME on my tables.

Is there a system stored procedure that returns both the contents/code of a store procedure and the dependent table which will then allow me to do a join on a filtered list of tables?

Cheers!

EDIT1:

Im looking to programatically rename the stored procedures not track dependencies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a simliar question to this (link below) with a sample of a scipt I use to find text in stored procedures (and functions and views). It requires a bit of work, but might help you here.

[[How to find data table column reference in stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111709/how-to-find-data-table-column-reference-in-stored-procedures/1111932#1111932][1])

[1]: http://How to find data table column reference in stored procedures

Comment: Hmm, can't say I'm too impressed with that Hyperlink editing option -- or what did I get wrong?

Comment: lol dont worry about it. gonna try out your script later. seems to be on the right track from my initial glance

Answer (score 2):

The built-in dependency tracking for SQL isn't very good for this type of work.  Two tools come to mind thought...

1. Red Gate SQL Dependency Tracker - Good for determining all the dependent code
2. Visual Studio for Database Developers - Contains TSQL Code Analysis which can identify if a piece of data is being treated as an incorrect type.

Red Gate has a free trial on their stuff, which might get you through this job

Comment: Sorry I wasnt very clear with my question but the Red Gate tools would not be helpful for my purposes. (I need to change the input variables of affected stored procedures programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

If your dependencies in SQL Server are accurate, you can use sys.sql_dependencies with appropriate joins.